# Update element's class during Backbone.Render when element is generated from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm wondering if this is best practice or if I'm missing an easy way of dynamically modifying an element's class:

```
define(function () {
    'use strict';

    var NextButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({

        className: 'disabled halfGradient',

        template: _.template($('#nextButtonTemplate').html()),

        attributes: function() {

            return {
                id: 'NextButton',
                title: chrome.i18n.getMessage("skipNextVideo")
            };
        },

        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            this.$el.toggleClass('disabled', !this.model.get('enabled'));
            return this;
        },

        initialize: function () {
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:enabled', this.render);
        }

    });

    return NextButtonView;
});
```

where my template is:

```
<script type="text/template" id="nextButtonTemplate">

    <svg width="16px" height="16px">
        <rect class="path" x="14" y="3" width="2" height="10" fill="gray" />
        <path class="path" d="M0,3 L7,8 L0,13z" fill="gray" />
        <path class="path" d="M7,3 L14,8, L7,13z" fill="gray" />
    </svg> 

</script>
```

Is there a more 'implicit' way of setting the class based on the model's state?

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with what you have, but you can also do the following:

```
className: function() {
    return 'halfGradient' + ( this.model.get('enabled') ? '' : ' disabled');
},
//...
```